# visNetwork selectedBy (visOptions function) for multiple columns

Tags: visnetwork

I have written code for a visNetwork network. Within the visOptions function, it can currently select node by id (using nodesIdSelection) as well as select nodes using values from a particular column (using selectedBy). I have looked through the documentation to see how to select nodes using additional columns (i.e. multiple drop down lists in HTML) but can't find the syntax.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try to use the [DataSet](http://visjs.org/docs/data/dataset.html) get method with your prefered options.

then you can select the returned array to select your nodes.